# Question about graded algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

I have the following question. Let us suppose that we have a  $\mathbb{Z}$- graded algebra $R$ with generators  $a_{1},...,a_{r}$ in degrees $d_{1},...,d_{r}$ respectively. What kind of conditions we need to impose on $R$ in order to verify:
$$R_{i}\otimes R_{j}\simeq R_{i+j}$$
for all $i$ and $j$?

Comment: What do you mean by generators? Is your algebra finitely generated? Also, with respect to what ground ring is the tensor product being taken?